# Migrate ubuntu install to another drive on the same computer

Tags: boot, grub2, backup, raid, deja-dup

I want to migrate all my current data, that includes files, desktop, home folder, programs and even open tabs in browser and history to another volume at the same computer without having boot/grub issues. I tried to clone with dd but I was unable o boot then. I can't unplug my main storage device and I think it is the main boot device where EFI partition must be. Those disks are on RAID mode. Tried Balena Etcher, but got the same result as before, tried to copy files from apt and home to another fresh install but those files are inaccessible due to belonging to another user. Heard about Deja-dup, anyone could confirm and give me more instructions in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here I go answering my own question. The best approach I found was to use the dump and restore commands, which can be installed through apt. The file created by dumb is filesystem agnostic, so your back up will be safely stored in any other volume no matter what filesystem it uses without affecting other files if it has enough space. I order to restore you just need boot from a live session and run the restore command after temporarily installing it with apt or permanently if you are in live session like me.

```
sudo apt install dump
sudo dump -0uan -f path_to_external_vol/backup /
```

The code above will copy all your files to a binary on the drive of your choice. Once you booted on your live session, run this.

```
sudo restore -r -f path_to_target_partition path_to_your_backup_file
```

If you don't have a large enough drive to store your backup dd remains the most fitting choice to use with care, I heard about Rsync, but hasn't the opportunity to use.